# Why is there an error in swift grammar

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

The tool involved is Xcode7.2, which is installed using  CocoaPod

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
```

However, there is a large number of compilation errors as shown in the picture. Can I ask why are these errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#selector` special form was added in Swift 2.2, which is shipped with Xcode 7.3. You're using Xcode 7.2. You need to either upgrade Xcode, or use a slightly older version of AlamoFire.